# Artifacts from linear filtering a floating point texture in the fragment shader

Tags: opengl-es, glsl, webgl, fragment-shader

I'm using the following code taken from [this tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/236394/Bi-Cubic-and-Bi-Linear-Interpolation-with-GLSL) to perform linear filtering on a floating point texture in my fragment shader in WebGL:

```
float fHeight = 512.0;
float fWidth = 1024.0;
float texelSizeX = 1.0/fWidth;
float texelSizeY = 1.0/fHeight;

float tex2DBiLinear( sampler2D textureSampler_i, vec2 texCoord_i )
{
    float p0q0 = texture2D(textureSampler_i, texCoord_i)[0];
    float p1q0 = texture2D(textureSampler_i, texCoord_i + vec2(texelSizeX, 0))[0];

    float p0q1 = texture2D(textureSampler_i, texCoord_i + vec2(0, texelSizeY))[0];
    float p1q1 = texture2D(textureSampler_i, texCoord_i + vec2(texelSizeX , texelSizeY))[0];

    float a = fract( texCoord_i.x * fWidth ); // Get Interpolation factor for X direction.
                    // Fraction near to valid data.

    float pInterp_q0 = mix( p0q0, p1q0, a ); // Interpolates top row in X direction.
    float pInterp_q1 = mix( p0q1, p1q1, a ); // Interpolates bottom row in X direction.

    float b = fract( texCoord_i.y * fHeight );// Get Interpolation factor for Y direction.
    return mix( pInterp_q0, pInterp_q1, b ); // Interpolate in Y direction.
}
```

On an Nvidia GPU this looks fine, but on two other computers with an Intel integrated GPU it looks like this:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

There are lighter or darker lines appearing that shouldn't be there. They become visible if you zoom in, and tend to get more frequent the more you zoom. When zooming in very closely, they appear at the edge of every texel of the texture I'm filtering. I tried changing the precision statement in the fragment shader, but this didn't fix it.

The built-in linear filtering works on both GPUs, but I still need the manual filtering as a fallback for GPUs that don't support linear filtering on floating point textures with WebGL.

The Intel GPUs are from a desktop Core i5-4460 and a notebook with an Intel HD 5500 GPU. For all precisions of floating point values I get a rangeMin and rangeMax of 127 and a precision of 23 from `getShaderPrecisionFormat`.

Any idea on what causes these artifacts and how I can work around it?

**Edit:**

By experimenting a bit more I found that reducing the texel size variable in the fragment shader removes these artifacts:

```
float texelSizeX = 1.0/fWidth*0.998;
float texelSizeY = 1.0/fHeight*0.998;
```

Multiplying by 0.999 isn't enough, but multiplying the texel size by 0.998 removes the artifacts.

This is obviously not a satisfying fix, I still don't know what causes it and I probably caused artifacts on other GPUs or drivers now. So I'm still interested in figuring out what the actual issue is here.

Comment: "*I tried changing the precision statement in the fragment shader, but this didn't fix it.*" What happens if you *lower* the precision of the NVIDIA version?

Comment: @NicolBolas I'll have to recheck, but I think it still looked fine and didn't cause any artifacts. But I'm also not sure if the precision statements actually result in any lower precision on the NVIDIA GPU.

Comment: Also, could you add a few different resolution versions of the Intel one? Oh and one more thing: can you verify if the color of those lines is always the same?

Comment: @NicolBolas I added more images, and the colors aren't the same. But I also found a workaround now that removes the lines, though I still don't understand the issue.

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear to me what the code is trying to do. It's not reproducing the GPU's bilinear because that would be using pixels centered around the texcoord.

In other words, as implemented

```
vec4 c = tex2DBiLinear(someSampler, someTexcoord);
```

is **NOT** equivilent to `LINEAR`

```
vec4 c = texture2D(someSampler, someTexcoord);
```

`texture2D` looks at pixels `someTexcoord +/- texelSize * .5` where as `tex2DBiLinear` is looking at pixels `someTexcoord` and `someTexcoord + texelSize`

You haven't given enough code to repo your issue. I'm guessing the size of the source texture is 512x1024 but since you didn't post that code I have no idea if your source texture matches the defined size. You also didn't post what size your target is. The top image you posted is 471x488. Was that your target size? You also didn't post your code for what texture coordinates you're using and the code that manipulates them.

Guessing that your source is 512x1024, your target is 471x488 I can't repo your issue.

```js
const fs = `
precision highp float;

uniform sampler2D tex;
varying vec2 v_texcoord;

float tex2DBiLinear( sampler2D textureSampler_i, vec2 texCoord_i )
{
float fHeight = 1024.0;
float fWidth = 512.0;
float texelSizeX = 1.0/fWidth;
float texelSizeY = 1.0/fHeight;

    float p0q0 = texture2D(textureSampler_i, texCoord_i)[0];
    float p1q0 = texture2D(textureSampler_i, texCoord_i + vec2(texelSizeX, 0))[0];

    float p0q1 = texture2D(textureSampler_i, texCoord_i + vec2(0, texelSizeY))[0];
    float p1q1 = texture2D(textureSampler_i, texCoord_i + vec2(texelSizeX , texelSizeY))[0];

    float a = fract( texCoord_i.x * fWidth ); // Get Interpolation factor for X direction.
                    // Fraction near to valid data.

    float pInterp_q0 = mix( p0q0, p1q0, a ); // Interpolates top row in X direction.
    float pInterp_q1 = mix( p0q1, p1q1, a ); // Interpolates bottom row in X direction.

    float b = fract( texCoord_i.y * fHeight );// Get Interpolation factor for Y direction.
    return mix( pInterp_q0, pInterp_q1, b ); // Interpolate in Y direction.
}

void main() {
  gl_FragColor = vec4(tex2DBiLinear(tex, v_texcoord), 0, 0, 1);
}
`;

const vs = `
attribute vec4 position;
attribute vec2 texcoord;
varying vec2 v_texcoord;
void main() {
  gl_Position = position;
  v_texcoord = texcoord;
}
`;

const gl = document.querySelector('canvas').getContext('webgl');
// compile shaders, link programs, look up locations
const programInfo = twgl.createProgramInfo(gl, [vs, fs]);
// calls gl.createBuffer, gl.bindBuffer, gl.bufferData for each array
const bufferInfo = twgl.createBufferInfoFromArrays(gl, {
  position: {
    numComponents: 2,
    data: [
      -1, -1,
       1, -1,
      -1,  1,
       1,  1,
    ],
  },
  texcoord: [
    0, 0,
    1, 0,
    0, 1,
    1, 1,
  ],
  indices: [
    0, 1, 2,
    2, 1, 3,
  ],
});


const ctx = document.createElement('canvas').getContext('2d');
ctx.canvas.width = 512;
ctx.canvas.height = 1024;
const gradient = ctx.createRadialGradient(256, 512, 0, 256, 512, 700);

gradient.addColorStop(0, 'red');
gradient.addColorStop(1, 'cyan');
ctx.fillStyle = gradient;
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 512, 1024);

const tex = twgl.createTexture(gl, {
  src: ctx.canvas,
  minMag: gl.NEAREST,
  wrap: gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE,
  auto: false,
});

gl.useProgram(programInfo.program);
// calls gl.bindBuffer, gl.enableVertexAttribArray, gl.vertexAttribPointer
twgl.setBuffersAndAttributes(gl, programInfo, bufferInfo);
// calls gl.drawArrays or gl.drawElements
twgl.drawBufferInfo(gl, bufferInfo);
```

```html
<script src="https://twgljs.org/dist/4.x/twgl-full.min.js"></script>
<canvas width="471" height="488"></canvas>
```

If you think the issue is related to floating point textures I can't repo there either

```js
const fs = `
precision highp float;

uniform sampler2D tex;
varying vec2 v_texcoord;

float tex2DBiLinear( sampler2D textureSampler_i, vec2 texCoord_i )
{
float fHeight = 1024.0;
float fWidth = 512.0;
float texelSizeX = 1.0/fWidth;
float texelSizeY = 1.0/fHeight;

    float p0q0 = texture2D(textureSampler_i, texCoord_i)[0];
    float p1q0 = texture2D(textureSampler_i, texCoord_i + vec2(texelSizeX, 0))[0];

    float p0q1 = texture2D(textureSampler_i, texCoord_i + vec2(0, texelSizeY))[0];
    float p1q1 = texture2D(textureSampler_i, texCoord_i + vec2(texelSizeX , texelSizeY))[0];

    float a = fract( texCoord_i.x * fWidth ); // Get Interpolation factor for X direction.
                    // Fraction near to valid data.

    float pInterp_q0 = mix( p0q0, p1q0, a ); // Interpolates top row in X direction.
    float pInterp_q1 = mix( p0q1, p1q1, a ); // Interpolates bottom row in X direction.

    float b = fract( texCoord_i.y * fHeight );// Get Interpolation factor for Y direction.
    return mix( pInterp_q0, pInterp_q1, b ); // Interpolate in Y direction.
}

void main() {
  gl_FragColor = vec4(tex2DBiLinear(tex, v_texcoord), 0, 0, 1);
}
`;

const vs = `
attribute vec4 position;
attribute vec2 texcoord;
varying vec2 v_texcoord;
void main() {
  gl_Position = position;
  v_texcoord = texcoord;
}
`;

const gl = document.querySelector('canvas').getContext('webgl');
const ext = gl.getExtension('OES_texture_float');
if (!ext) { alert('need OES_texture_float'); }
// compile shaders, link programs, look up locations
const programInfo = twgl.createProgramInfo(gl, [vs, fs]);
// calls gl.createBuffer, gl.bindBuffer, gl.bufferData for each array
const bufferInfo = twgl.createBufferInfoFromArrays(gl, {
  position: {
    numComponents: 2,
    data: [
      -1, -1,
       1, -1,
      -1,  1,
       1,  1,
    ],
  },
  texcoord: [
    0, 0,
    1, 0,
    0, 1,
    1, 1,
  ],
  indices: [
    0, 1, 2,
    2, 1, 3,
  ],
});


const ctx = document.createElement('canvas').getContext('2d');
ctx.canvas.width = 512;
ctx.canvas.height = 1024;
const gradient = ctx.createRadialGradient(256, 512, 0, 256, 512, 700);

gradient.addColorStop(0, 'red');
gradient.addColorStop(1, 'cyan');
ctx.fillStyle = gradient;
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 512, 1024);

const tex = twgl.createTexture(gl, {
  src: ctx.canvas,
  type: gl.FLOAT,
  minMag: gl.NEAREST,
  wrap: gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE,
  auto: false,
});

gl.useProgram(programInfo.program);
// calls gl.bindBuffer, gl.enableVertexAttribArray, gl.vertexAttribPointer
twgl.setBuffersAndAttributes(gl, programInfo, bufferInfo);
// calls gl.drawArrays or gl.drawElements
twgl.drawBufferInfo(gl, bufferInfo);
const e = gl.getExtension('WEBGL_debug_renderer_info');
if (e) {
  console.log(gl.getParameter(e.UNMASKED_VENDOR_WEBGL));
  console.log(gl.getParameter(e.UNMASKED_RENDERER_WEBGL));
}
```

```html
<script src="https://twgljs.org/dist/4.x/twgl-full.min.js"></script>
<canvas width="471" height="488"></canvas>
```

If any of the values are off. If your source texture size doesn't match `fWidth` and `fHeigth` or if your texture coordinates are different or adjusted in some way then of course maybe I could repo. If any of those are different then I can imagine issues.

Tested in Intel Iris Pro and Intel HD Graphics 630. Also tested on an iPhone6+. Note that you need to make sure your fragment shader is running in `precision highp float` but that setting would likely only affect mobile GPUs.

Comment: Not sure why someone bountied this more than 3 years later, the code looks a bit different today than in my original question. It's certainly very interesting that the function itself doesn't seem to be the issue, though I'm pretty sure the texture sizes match as the current code doesn't use hardcoded values anymore. I don't have access to the old computers to reproduce the same conditions, I'll have to see if I can reproduce this again today with different Intel hardware and driver versions.

Comment: I added the bounty.  I see the same issue as described in the original post on an iMac Radeon Pro 580.  @gman, your explanation of how it works in texture2D is helpful, but it only shifted the artifact, didn't make it go away.  I see the issue using various texture sizes and seems more pronounced the more zoom is involved.

Comment: I'm not sure about what Mad Scientist was trying to do, but I need to do some integer math in my shader, for which interpolation will cause problems.  Both preprocessing the texture data and drawing to offscreen buffer without interp are too high in terms of performance cost.  I still want the final result to appear smooth though, so I thought doing bilinear interpolation in the shader would be a good solution all around.  It works great except for this strange artifact, exactly as described above.  Mad Scientist's suggested solution does work, but I wish there was another way.

Comment: @whiskeyspider. Just to confirm, you're seeing the artifact using the snippets in this answer on your iMac Radeon Pro 580?

Comment: @gman No, I'm not able to recreate it with your snippets, like I can with my own code, so it must be involve something else.  I'll try to put together some sample code that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: Once you are able to repo please ask a new question 

Answer (score 1):

We had almost identical issue that ocurred at specific zoom of texture. We found out that positions where artifacts appers can be detected with this conditions:

```
vec2 imagePosCenterity = fract(uv * imageSize);
if (abs(imagePosCenterity.x-0.5) < 0.001 || abs(imagePosCenterity.y-0.5) < 0.001) {}
```

Where `imageSize` is width and height of the texture.

Our solution looks like this:

```
vec4 texture2DLinear( sampler2D texSampler, vec2 uv) {
    vec2 pixelOff = vec2(0.5,0.5)/imageSize;

    vec2 imagePosCenterity = fract(uv * imageSize);
    if (abs(imagePosCenterity.x-0.5) < 0.001 || abs(imagePosCenterity.y-0.5) < 0.001) {
        pixelOff = pixelOff-vec2(0.00001,0.00001);
    }

    vec4 tl = texture2D(texSampler, uv + vec2(-pixelOff.x,-pixelOff.y));
    vec4 tr = texture2D(texSampler, uv + vec2(pixelOff.x,-pixelOff.y));
    vec4 bl = texture2D(texSampler, uv + vec2(-pixelOff.x,pixelOff.y));
    vec4 br = texture2D(texSampler, uv + vec2(pixelOff.x,pixelOff.y));
    vec2 f = fract( (uv.xy-pixelOff) * imageSize );
    vec4 tA = mix( tl, tr, f.x );
    vec4 tB = mix( bl, br, f.x );
    return mix( tA, tB, f.y );
}
```

It is really dirty solution but it works. Changing texelSize as suggested above only moves artifacts to another positions. We are changing texelSize a little bit only on problematic positions.

Why we are using linear texture interpolation in GLSL shader? It is because we need to use 1 sample per pixel 16 bit per sample texture with broad set of compatibile devices. It is possible to do it only with [OES_texture_half_float_linear extension](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/OES_texture_half_float_linear). By our approach it is possible to solve it without using extension.

Comment: Thanks this was really helpful.  I noticed the same thing, except my artifacts aligned with the texel edges.  Replacing 0.5 with 1.0, fixed the issue for me.